# Java string - get everything between (but not including) two regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

In Java, is there a simple way to extract a substring by specifying the regular expression delimiters on either side, without including the delimiters in the final substring?

For example, if I have a string like this:

```
<row><column>Header text</column></row>
```

what is the easiest way to extract the substring:

```
Header text
```

Please note that the substring may contain line breaks...

thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Write a regex like this:

```
"(regex1)(.*)(regex2)"
```

... and pull out the middle group from the matcher (to handle newlines in your pattern you want to use [Pattern.DOTALL](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL)).

Using your example we can write a program like:

```
package test;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Regex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
                "<row><column>(.*)</column></row>",
                Pattern.DOTALL
            );

        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(
                "<row><column>Header\n\n\ntext</column></row>"
            );

        if(matcher.matches()){
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }

}
```

Which when run prints out:

```
Header


text
```

Comment: @Adam ... it's only because I needed to fire up Eclipse to get an example and wanted to get an answer up quickly ;)

Comment: @Aaron:  fair enough.  I may as well delete my first comment then :)  Nice answer.

Comment: @Aaron - thank you, your example works! 

But please could you tell me what regular expression pattern to use to extract the same text from a string like this, which includes some single quotes?

<row><column name='title'>Header\n\n\ntext</column></row>

I've tried using   

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
                "<row><column name='title'>(.*)</column></row>",
                Pattern.DOTALL
            );

and the same but with backslashes in front of the quotes, but neither work.

Sorry, I am very new to regular expressions, appreciate the help.

Thank you again!

Anna

Comment: Anna, that's why it is easier to just use the proper tool to parse XML: an XML parser.  XML is not a regular language, so don't try to parse it with regular expressions.

Comment: Awakening the dead here.. just a quick tip: you might want to use `matcher.find()` instead of `matches()`, in case the string you are searching in is larger than the bit that you're interested in.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use regular expressions to decode XML - this will eventually break if the input is not strictly controlled.

The easiest thing is probably to parse the XML up in a DOM tree (Java 1.4 and newer contain a XML parser directly) and then navigate the tree to pick out what you need.

Perhaps you would like to tell what you want to accomplish with your program?

Comment: +1 once you've got a DOM tree you can use XPath to pull out the bits you want.