# Android : How to Parse HTML tags and retrieve information from an HTML page

Tags: android, html, xml, parsing, rss

I'm trying to get live cricket scores from a cricket site.
Part of the HTML source is as follows.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://developers.facebook.com/schema/">

<head>

 <meta name="google-site-verification" content="ZxdgH3XglRg0Bsy-Ho2RnO3EE4nRs53FloLS6fkt_nc" />

 <title>Eng 132/4 (29.3 ov, MJ Prior 27*, IJL Trott 53*, JM Davison 0/10) | Live Scorecard | ESPN Cricinfo</title> 

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

 <meta name="keywords" content="Canada v England, Live cricket score, Khan Shaheb Osman Ali Stadium, Fatullah, Fatullah, Other one-day/limited-overs matches" />

 <meta name="description" content="Live cricket score and commentary for ICC World Cup Warm-up Matches, Canada v England at Fatullah, Feb 16, 2011" />
```

My point of interest is the `<title>` tag. How do I parse through the file and retrieve
info on the title tag?

P.S. I get the above HTML link from an XML file.
Am planning to use the code in the following link to parse through the XML file
and retrieve the T

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/

Regards,
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open an stream to read through the contents of the URL, and then extract words between `<title>` and `</title>` tags with the help of `String.substring()` and `String.indeOf()` methods (The dirty way). or follow what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962122/java-string-get-everything-between-but-not-including-two-regular-expressions/962137#962137) link says (regex)