# Read a file from one point or word in a file to another specific point or word

Tags: java

I will like some guidance and if possible skeletal sample code as to how to take care of this project.

I have a file that contains text and I want to start reading this text from a particular point and end at a particular point in the file and then skip some lines and continue again.

I want to read everything between **objective** and **end of time** and skip to the next **objective** and read everything in between and continue to the end of the file in that format

This is what I mean..   Sample File

this is the begining of the end and it is all we can fadom at the moment
**Objectives**
who has authority to: access to the IMG access to the above tables
ensure the access matches the company defined roleverify 
**end of time**
no one is the wiser after something like that happens
laughing at the wrong person mate
**objective**
Come to think of it no one can actually see how a tree grows but it does right
**end of time**
we are done with those and now we have things to do

Comment: Read until you find the start point, then continue reading to the end point, while saving the data you read in-between.  Simple.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way may be to use regular expressions, like here:  [Java string - get everything between (but not including) two regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962122/java-string-get-everything-between-but-not-including-two-regular-expressions).  I haven't written Java in some time, so the syntax might be off but it should be close.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Regex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
                "Objective (.*) end of time",
                Pattern.DOTALL
            );

        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(
                "this objective is the test end of time"
            );

        if(matcher.matches()){
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }

}
```